# World map and photo storage

Tags: online-resources, maps, photography, mobile-apps

I like to travel and I take many pictures while traveling.
I wish to have a place where I could save my photos and save the location where it was taken.

I currently use instagram to do so but since it's a social media everything is shared with everyone and, well, I want to keep my photos private. (and I don't want to set up my account private, I just prefer not to send my personal photos to instagram)

Instagram has the exact feature I want to have: be able to see photos where there were taken on a world map.
Here's the feature I'm speaking about:

[image]

Is there an free and private service which offers the feature I'm looking for?
Is there a free tool that I just have to install on a NAS to have this feature on a web interface?

EDIT: I need that tool / service includes an interface to add localisation information as most of my photos don't have these information. I also want my photos to be available online through a webpage.

Comment: This sounds like a perfect question for softwarerecs.stackexchange

Comment: Instagram has all the features you're asking for, and has a way to make your photos private. So use Instagram. If you want to be able to simultaneously post public photos then maintain a second account! (I'm surprised Instagram doesn't have per-image privacy settings?)

Comment: apple announced a feature that looks like that at wwdc, should be publicly available in fall.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit but this instagram feature is only available on apps, not on their website ...

Comment: Aha! That's a key point.

Answer (score 8):

When you say you want to keep them private, does that mean you want them on the web but only visible to you or you want to keep them only on your computer ?

I know that Adobe Lightroom does that.

Here's a video showing the feature : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnSXz0ckFno

Flickr also support that that. (the only one I checked, I assume other site like smugmug, picasaweb support **geotagging**)

You could also ask on photo.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Yes I meant I want them to be visible online. The three websites you speak about ain't social networks ? I prefer to host the photos on my own hardware / website but they are solution to what I want.

Comment: with flickr and others, you can set albums private.
As for hosting that yourself, I don't have a clue at this time (sorry)

Comment: I've checked Flickr, I cannot add localisation information to a photo which does not have geotag information... My camera does not provide geotag information, I'd like to add them when uploading the photos on the website / tool.

Comment: When you have one of your photos open in Flickr, you should have the option 'add to the map' which is a world map with zoom in function down to at least one street and often down to the single house in a city. Not sure all accounts have it though.

Comment: @Willeke Thanks! Just found it! But could not use it easily, it's really not smooth so I'm still looking for better solution if it exists :)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using your smart phone to take pictures, both Google and Apple have this functionality built into their respective platforms.

https://support.google.com/plus/answer/6008918?hl=en

http://www.cultofmac.com/266849/see-took-photos-iphone-ios-tips/

Comment: I currently use an android phone but who knows if I'll still use it in few weeks... Plus I'd like to have a solution which allow me to easily add photos from a camera (which is not running android and does not provide localization information)

Answer (score 0):

Picasa has a feature to tag place, people and date/time on pictures, and afaik also view the map with all the thumbnails.

Comment: To be sure I'll check and report back (if I remember :))